# Filter in GET with loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to GET users with a specific filter (such as the email is equal to "e@e.e").
The description says `Filter defining fields, where, include, order, offset, and limit - must be a JSON-encoded string ({"something":"value"})`, however typing `{"email":"ju@ju.ju"}` simply gets all the users instead of just this one.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should post your query url which looks something like this: `http://localhost:3000/api/Model?filter=%7B%20%22where%22%3A%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22icecream%22%7D%20%7D`

But if I had to guess, you aren't using a `filter` or `where` key in your object.

`{"filter": {"key": "value"} }` incorrect

`{"where": {"key": "value"} }` correct for the ***api explorer*** (because it puts `filter` there for you), incorrect for ***anything else***

`{"filter": {"where": {"key": "value"} } }` correct